# Will The Asus PTGD-LA socket LGA775 Support A quad core Processor or what is the fastest processor it will support?

Tags: windows-xp

Will The Asus PTGD-LA socket LGA775 Support A quad core Processor or what is the fastest processor it will support?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest processor it will support is a 3.4 Ghz Pentium 4 with HT. ASUS does not have documentation for this board on their site though as far as I know, but [HP does](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c00361570#N852) (it seems to have been made specifically for HP).

Comment: I don't believe ASUS ever supported it on their site. It looks as if it was OEMed specifically for HP, making them responsible for support. Either way, you are right. The 915 chipset never even supported dual cores, nevermind quad. +1